# Using Html.fromHTML with an <a> tag won't color!

Tags: java, android, html

I'm trying to use the Android Html.fromHtml method to parse a text like a tweet with @ mentions in it. However, I have the username of the current user and I wish to highlight this to the user as being themselves.

I'm trying to with this code, which doesn't work:

`in = in.replace("@" + u.username, "@<font background=#0099ff color=#fff><a href='dailybooth://user/"+
                    u.username+"'>"+u.username+"</a></font>");`

In theory, I think it should work, however it doesn't color at all!

Comment: this is tougher than it should be. I definitely learned something because of this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be a doozy.

Neither the `font` tag nor inline styles on the `a` tag worked for me. **I had to resort to using Spannables directly**:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("");
String linkName = "@appamatto";
String linkUrl = "http://twitter.com/appamatto"
SpannableString str = SpannableString.valueOf(linkName);
str.setSpan(new URLSpan(linkUrl), 0, linkName.length(),
    Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xffffffff), 0, linkName.length(),
    Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
str.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xff0099ff), 0, linkName.length(),
    Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
text.append(str);
```

This will, for example, set the colors of the link in the way you wanted. You can look for other Spannables in [android.text.style](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary.html) to achieve other effects.

**Edit** for replace you could do something like:

```
String[] components = in.split("@" + u.username, -1);
text.append(components[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < components.length; i++) {
    text.append(str); // using the spannable from above
    text.append(components[i]);
}
```

The -1 in `split()` is what you would need to deal with matches coming at the end of strings, as per the [split docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Comment: AFAIK, `background` is not a supported attribute for `font` tags with `Html.fromHtml()`. However, I agree that quotation marks (*not* apostrophes, as in the `a` tag in the code shown in the question) are probably needed.

Comment: I'll try this out when I'm next on my computer. Sounds promising! :D

Comment: I can't seem to use it as a replace item, as I need to make it replace the "@name" in the actual text given from the server